Two Grothendieck groups for rings are the same for f.g. algebras over fields
Wikipedia states that:

In the case where R is a finite-dimensional algebra over some field, the Grothendieck groups $G_0(R)$ (defined via short exact sequences of finitely generated modules) and $K_0(R)$ (defined via direct sum of finitely generated projective modules) coincide. In fact, both groups are isomorphic to the free abelian group generated by the isomorphism classes of simple R-modules.

Why is this true? I am interested in an explicit isomorphism if one is known.

The text here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1524874 seems to be related

Well, whether that is true depends a bit on what you mean by "the same".
$G_0(R)$ has a basis consisting of the isomorphism classes of simple $R$-modules, and $K_0(R)$ has a basis given by the isomorphism classes of indecomposable projective $R$-modules, and there is a natural bijection between (isomorphism classes of) simples and indecomposable projectives, sending a simple module to its projective cover, and sending an indecomposable projective to its unique simple quotient.
So $G_0(R)$ and $K_0(R)$ are free abelian groups of the same rank, and therefore isomorphic.
However, the most natural map between them is the map $K_0(R)\to G_0(R)$ that sends the class of a projective module $P$ in $K_0(R)$ to its class in $G_0(R)$, and this is not an isomorphism in general. So I would say that $G_0(R)$ and $K_0(R)$ are isomorphic, rather than "the same".
